# regopenkeyex returns 2 on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I have a 32 bit program which is running in two lanes in the same store. The program tries top open a registry key for query. The operating system is Windows 8.1 64 bit.

On one lane it succeeds, and on the other it fails and regopenkeyex returns 2. GetLastError returns 0.

The key it tries to open is under WOW6432Node.

The program is running under the same Windows user on both machines, the key exists on both. the UAC is set to "Never notify" (lowest), windows version is the same. Everything is supposed to be the same...

I am deliberately not specifying KEY_WOW64_64KEY because the code is supposed to work without it. But even when I do use it I get the same result.

What could be causing this?

The code:

```
rc = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
               szKey,
                0,
                KEY_QUERY_VALUE,
                &m_hKey);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is szKey? What do you mean by two lanes in store?

Comment: 1. it does not matter what szKey is. 2. the program is running in a retail store which has several lanes (checkouts). It fails on one, works on others.

Comment: Of course it matters!

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to read about the functions you are using on MSDN. The registry functions return the error code directly, they do not use `GetLastError`!

2 is [`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) so whatever you are hiding in `szKey` is not a valid subkey path.

WOW6432Node is a reserved key name that you really should not be using, use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` if you need to access the 32-bit registry view in a 64-bit application. A 32-bit application reads keys under the WOW6432Node key by default.

Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to make sure you are accessing the correct key.

Comment: I do know that. You are giving negative feedback without understanding what I write. 
The key I read is something like this: 
"SOFTWARE\\XXX\\YYY\\ZZZ"
and XXX is found under WOW6432Node.

I wrote the function returns 2. So I call GetLastError as well, so what? the main thing is that the function returned 2, and the same program on a PC set up extctly the same returns 0.

I hope this is clear enough for you.

Comment: So one PC has the key and the other doesn't?

Comment: Both PC's have the key.

Comment: What does Process Monitor say?

Comment: So clearly the key is not there like I have been saying all along. It should not really be a problem, you are asking for KEY_QUERY_VALUE so this is a **read** operation and you should be able to handle the key/value not being there (user "cleaned" the registry etc.).